# How was the input field: top, left, & right border hidden in this code?

Tags: html, css

How was the input field: top, left, & right border hidden in [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OopJQx?editors=1100#0) (edited) code? (note: I changed/removed some things to make it easier/simpler for me, [this](https://codepen.io/atunnecliffe/pen/gpKzQw?editors=1100#0) is the original code)

I've been trying to figure out (in [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OopJQx?editors=1100#0) (edited) code) how does the page displays the input field (while not in focus) with the top, left, & right border hidden, and only bottom border shown?

I tried to hide top, left, & right borders like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLpWLz) (does works):

```
.input-field {
  background: transparent;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  background: transparent;
  outline: 0;
  height: 23px;
  border-color: black;
  width: 130px;
}
```

Now, I'm looking at the [CSS code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OopJQx?editors=1100#0) (edited) and try to find a similar code block with the ones I made above, but I couldn't find any that will hide the top, left, & right border, yet it still displays like that? this leaves a mystery to me.

Maybe `outline: 0;` does the work? if yes? could you please explain how.

`outline: 0;` only affect while the input field is in focus.The display will still the same [without outline](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mGWdQM?editors=1100#0) unless I start to focus on the input field.

Comment: That background transparent might be making the entire component invisible

Comment: @bobbybobbins yeah, I know about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are interested why that border appears there? This border is NOT the border or input. It is the border of `<label for="nme" style="font-size: 2px;"><span>Username</span></label>` for inputs spans and others, border is 0.

See this :

```
input, span, label, textarea {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}
```

> border: none > For 0 border of input.

```
input.question + label, textarea.question + label {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap; /* avoid label to go 2nd line*/
  width: 25%; /* default width*/
  border-top: 2px solid black; /* underline */
  margin-left: 450px; /* left position */
  height: 15px;
}
```

> border-top: 2px solid black;

and that `input.question + label` means that the style applies only to `label` directly following the `input.question` and same story with `textarea.question + label`

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the borders you see belong to a parent element or label because when I checked it in my system just on a lonely input, it worked correctly.